# addAtributeToFilter with custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, collection

This one work but is there a better way than this one or it's good

```
   ->addAttributeToFilter('promo', array('notnull'=>true))
```

Comment: whats the problem with that, you can try this to   `$_products->addAttributeToFilter('promo', array('neq' => ''));`

Comment: Thank you for your replay, there is no problem, I just wanted to make sure if there is a better way than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it is an EAV collection (for example product collection), and "promo" is a custom attribute, and you want to filter all entities where this attribute is not null:

This is the right way.